# Certificate signing with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, security, ssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Sorry for tons of code but haven't another way to explain my trouble.

**Steps:**

1. Generate key pair for `CN=localhost` with `makecert` (pvk and cer file);
2. Add cer file to Trusted Root Authorirties;
3. Convert (key pair => .pfx with `pvk2pfx` => .pem);
4. Load this key pair as pem file to my program;
5. Sign certificate for `example.com` with `BouncyCastle` (`issuerDN=localhost`, `subjectDN=example.com`);
6. Authenticate to client as server with generated certificate.

**Trouble:**
Browser warning that issuer of my certificate unknown.

Certificate for authentication is result of calling `SslSocketFactory.CreateKeyMaterial("example.com")`.

**What I am doing wrong ?**

Class that generate certificate:

```
public class SslSocketFactory
{

    private static string myCertPath = "MyCA.pem";
    private static string myPublCertPath = "MyCA.cer";

    private static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair LocalCertificate;
    private static X509Certificate PublicLocalCertificate;
    private static X509Certificate RemoteCertificate;
    private static System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain RemoteCertChain;

    public static System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 CreateKeyMaterial(string domainName)
    {

        ReadLocalCertificate(); // Reading Pem and Cer files
        LoadRemoteCert(domainName); // Loading Certificate from domain

        return CreateSelfSignedCertificate("CN=localhost"); 
    }

    private static void LoadRemoteCert(string domainName)
    {
        var server = new TcpClient();
        server.ConnectAsync(domainName, 443).Wait();
        var stream = new SslStream(server.GetStream(), true, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((a, b, c, d) => { RemoteCertChain = c; return true; }), null);
        stream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(domainName).Wait();
        RemoteCertificate = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(stream.RemoteCertificate.Export(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Cert));
    }

    private static void ReadLocalCertificate()
    {
        PublicLocalCertificate = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(
            new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(myPublCertPath)
            .Export(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Cert)
            );

        var fs = new FileStream(myCertPath, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr, new PemPassword());
        LocalCertificate = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();
        sr.Dispose();
        fs.Dispose();
    }

    public static System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificate(string issuerName)
    {
        var issuerPrivKey = LocalCertificate.Private;

        // Init Random 
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA256WITHRSA", issuerPrivKey, random);

        // Serial Number 
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // The Certificate Generator
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        var subjectKeyID = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(LocalCertificate.Public);
        var issuerKeyID = PublicLocalCertificate.CertificateStructure.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;

        certificateGenerator.CopyAndAddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, RemoteCertificate);
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id, false, new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(issuerKeyID, new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(new X509Name(PublicLocalCertificate.IssuerDN.ToString()))), PublicLocalCertificate.SerialNumber));
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifier(subjectKeyID));

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name(RemoteCertificate.SubjectDN.ToString());
        X509Name issuerDN = new X509Name(issuerName);
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

        // Valid For
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(10);

        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

        // Subject Public Key
        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(LocalCertificate.Public);

        // Generating a certificate
        X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
//Converting BC x509 to .net X509Certificate2, adding Private key 
        var p12Store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
        p12Store.SetKeyEntry("1", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(LocalCertificate.Private), new[] { new X509CertificateEntry(certificate) });
        var p12data = new MemoryStream();
        p12Store.Save(p12data, "password".ToCharArray(), new SecureRandom());

        var x509 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(p12data.ToArray(), "password", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        return x509;
    }

    class PemPassword : IPasswordFinder
    {
        public char[] GetPassword()
        {
            return "password".ToCharArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You created a self-signed root certificate that you used to sign your server certificate. The browser reported that the issuer was untrusted. Therefore everything worked the way it was supposed to.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeah, u are right, but i added my self-signed certificate to Windows Trusted Root Authorities. Browser should get my certificate as trusted, but aren't.

Comment: @VadimBugaiov That depends on a) which store you added this to b) which browser you use (firefox has it's own store) c) if the validity period is within time on the server c) if it's the server you're targeting, the Enhanched Key Usages have to be server auth and subject or SAN should match the URL f) if it's the client cert that the browser is complaining about, ensure you have EKU as client auth, and KU as signature and non repudiation